# How to disable touch on a CGRect / Sprite after one touch

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, touches

How can I disable touches for a CCRect / sprite after it has been touched?

I have in my init method to set the sprite:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"testAtlas_default.plist"];
            sceneSpriteBatchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"testAtlas_default.png"];

[self addChild:sceneSpriteBatchNode z:0];

dinosaur1_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur1-c.png"];
[sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur1_c];

[dinosaur1_c setPosition:CGPointMake(245.0, winSize.height - 174.0)];
```

I then create a CGRect using the position and size of the sprite as its parameters in:

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

    dinosaur1 = CGRectMake(dinosaur1_c.position.x - (dinosaur1_c.contentSize.width / 2), dinosaur1_c.position.y - (dinosaur1_c.contentSize.height / 2), dinosaur1_c.contentSize.width, dinosaur1_c.contentSize.height);

    if( CGRectContainsPoint(dinosaur1, touchLocation) )
    {
        CCLOG(@"Tapped Dinosaur1_c!");
        PLAYSOUNDEFFECT(PUZZLE_SKULL);

        //  Code to disable touches??
        //  Tried to resize CGRect in here to (0, 0, 1, 1) to get it away from the original sprite, but did not work.  Still was able to tap on CGRect.
        //  Tried [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] setDispatchEvents:NO];, but disables ALL the sprites instead of just this one.

    }
}
```

I'm able to successfully tap on the sprite to make it play the sound, however I just can't figure out how to disable the CGRect after it is touched.  I have tried different methods as commented in the code above.  Any ideas or tips are appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to return `NO` on  `ccTouchBegan:withEvent:`?

Comment: solved!  I will post up my solution as soon as stackoverflow allows me to.  I pretty much set a -(BOOL)isTapped to NO in my init method and when checking when it is tapped, I also check to see if it is != YES.  And in that method, I set isTapped to YES so the next time it comes around, it'll pass right through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I solved the problem.  In case anyone was wondering, I set up a -(BOOL)isTapped in my header file and set it to NO in my init method.

When I check for collisions with the touchpoint and the CGRect, I also check to see if isTapped != YES (meaning it hasnt been tapped yet).  In that if statement, I do all the actions as normally would but then set isTapped = YES.  Now it will skip over when I tap again.  Below is my code with the added bits in between *'s

```
.h file:

BOOL isTapped;
```

and in the .m file:

.m:

```
-(id)init
{
  isTapped = NO;
  // Rest of init method.
}

-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

    dinosaur1 = CGRectMake(dinosaur1_c.position.x - (dinosaur1_c.contentSize.width / 2), dinosaur1_c.position.y - (dinosaur1_c.contentSize.height / 2), dinosaur1_c.contentSize.width, dinosaur1_c.contentSize.height);

    if( CGRectContainsPoint(dinosaur1, touchLocation) **&& isTapped != YES**)
    {
        CCLOG(@"Tapped Dinosaur1_c!");
        PLAYSOUNDEFFECT(PUZZLE_SKULL);

        **isTapped = YES;**
    }
    else
    {
        CCLog(@"Already Tapped!");
    }
}
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

this will also help you

```
- (void)selectSpriteForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
 for (CCSprite *sprite in _projectiles) {

if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation)) {

    NSLog(@"sprite was touched");


    [sprite.parent removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];

    [self removeChild:sprite.parent cleanup:YES];

}
  }    }

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
[self selectSpriteForTouch:touchLocation];
NSLog(@"touch was _");
return TRUE;  }
```